# How to trim current filename of page from URL?

Tags: php

I have a method, it looks like this:

```
private function setURL()
{
    $pageURL = 'http';

    if(isset($_SERVER["HTTPS"]) && $_SERVER['HTTPS'] == "on")
    {
        $pageURL .= "s";
    }

    $pageURL .= "://";

    if($_SERVER["SERVER_PORT"] != "80")
    {
        $pageURL .= $_SERVER["SERVER_NAME"].":".$_SERVER["SERVER_PORT"].$_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"];
    }
    else
    {
        $pageURL .= $_SERVER["SERVER_NAME"].$_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"];
    }

    if(substr($pageURL, -4) == ".php")
    {
        // damn. this is harder to recover from.
        $len = strlen(basename(__FILE__, '.php'));
        $len = strlen($pageURL) - $len;
        $pageURL = substr($pageURL, 0, $len);
    }
    if(substr($pageURL, -1) != "/")
    {
        $pageURL .= "/";
    }

    $this->url = $pageURL;
}
```

If a user doesn't enter a filename, the URL returned is as expected, `http://localhost/zenbb2`. If the user does, however, the URL returned is wrong in some way, no matter what permutation I try to perform. For instance, this code returns `http://localhost` when visiting `http://localhost/zenbb2/index.php`, but `http://localhost/zenbb2` when visiting that URL.

**Edit** The contents of my .htaccess file are:

```
Options -indexes

RewriteEngine on
```

Also, I mean the current URL as in, if I were visiting `http://localhost/zenbb2/index.php`, it would trim the `index.php` from the URL so I can use it in various places in my code. Ideally, in the end, I could use it like this:

```
$url = 'http://localhost/zenbb2';
echo "<link rel=\"{$url}/sample.css\" />"; // http://localhost/zenbb2/sample.css
```

Comment: You want the current url of the page ??

Comment: Do you mean `$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']` or?

Comment: Could you show us your .htaccess. This might influence your method.

Comment: I've updated the title (unclear) and post. I tried `$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']` - it returned `zenbb2/index.php`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `dirname` to achieve this:

```
$ php -a
> $url = 'http://localhost/zenbb2/index.php';
> echo dirname($url);
http://localhost/zenbb2
```

Edit:
`dirname` always strips the last part of the string so use care to ensure you don't strip too much off but it can be useful when traversing URL or directory paths.

Comment: There's always a simple way. :P I've been using `dirname` extensively already in another part of the script, I'm surprised I didn't think of it. Thank you anyway.

Answer (score 0):

A better solution is to create a php file `config.php` then specify constants within it, after that, include the file everytime you want to use the URL. This solution is also implemented in well-known frameworks such as Codeigniter.

This approach is better, and frankly, more stable. For example, if you have a php file in a sub-directory (`/zenbb2/sub/file.php`) the URL directory would be `zenbb2/sub`, which, obviously, isn't what you're looking for, and your static files will return 404, since they don't exist there.

Comment: I will likely be doing that in the future, but I'm not currently developing the part that would control that (since it would be slightly more impractical to change that if I changed my domain name on a real server instead of localhost).

Answer (score 0):

Try this one

```
$url = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
echo basename($url);
```

This should give `index.php` from `http://localhost/zenbb2/index.php`